# Signal receiver threads in C and pthread_join stalling program

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm trying to build a basic program which has 2/3 threads. The main thread, signaler thread, and receiver thread. I'm trying to make it so the main thread starts both a signaler and receiver thread. The signaler thread is then supposed to send 10 SIGUSR1 signals to the receiver thread and increase a global counter. The receiver thread is supposed to receive the 10 signals while increasing its own counter for each signal received.

The trouble I'm having is with joining the threads back together at the end, specifically joining the receiver thread. The majority of the time the program stalls if I try to join them back together, I assume because the receiver thread hasn't finished its job (maybe it has missed signals?) and so it never finishes. I thought maybe this was the case, so I introduced a wait command in the signaler thread to slow it down, but that didn't change anything.

If I comment out the pthread_join(receiver, NULL) then  the program runs, but it only catches one signal most of the time. I assume this is because the receiver thread isn't getting much time to run. (although sometimes it catches various amounts, depending on when it was preempted?)

Leaving the pthread_join(receiver, NULL) in the program makes it stall 19/20 times, but that 1/20 time the program returns 10 signals sent and 10 received. This leads me to believe it has something to do with preemption, but I don't understand why it would ever stall in the first place.

Also right now I just have the receiver thread receiving threads while the received counter is < 10. Ideally I would just want to leave it in while(1) loop, but then again I don't know how to join that back into the main thread without freezing everything.

If someone could help me figure out why signals are being missed / why the program is freezing I would be most grateful. I have a suspicion that I'm not setting up the signal mask correctly for the receiver, but I don't know how else I am supposed to do it. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void *receivetest(void *args);
void *signaltest(void *args);


int received = 0;
int sent = 0;
pthread_t signaler;
pthread_t receiver;
sigset_t mask;

int main(){

    //setting up the signal mask
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);

    //creation of both threads
    pthread_create(&receiver, NULL, receivetest, NULL);
    pthread_create(&signaler, NULL, signaltest, NULL);


    pthread_join(signaler, NULL);
    pthread_join(receiver, NULL);

    //printing results after joining them back
    printf("I'm the main function\n");
    printf("Receieved: %d, sent: %d\n", received, sent);


}

void *signaltest(void *args){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){ //sends 10 signals to receiver thread
        pthread_kill(receiver, SIGUSR1);
        sent++;
    }
}

void *receivetest(void *args){
    int c; //sigwait needs int 
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL); //sets up the signal mask for this thread
    while(received < 10){ //waits for 10 signals and increments receieved
        sigwait(&mask, &c);
        received++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why are you trying to use signals as an inter-thread communication mechanism?

Comment: `pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);` means block all signals defined in `mask`. This should be placed in the main thread so any signals reaching main thread will be passed to signal handler. This means the signal receiver never processed any signals. It blocked them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right. It is recommended to block the signals from the main thread to protect all new threads from mishandling the signal.

Any thread created after `pthread_sigmask()`, inherits the sigmask. The first parameter tells `pthread_sigmask()` what to do with the signals listed in the second parameter.

This line `pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL)` should be placed in the main thread, not on the signal handler. Your original code will work too, but if the signal is sent to the wrong thread, it will kill the whole process.

In addition, the sender is sending signal faster than the receiver can handle. By sleeping for 1 second between each iteration, the receiver will be able to catch up.

I took the liberty and modified your code. I added some prints within the sender and receiver so you'll know what it is doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void receivetest(void); //function does not return anything
void signaltest(void); // does not accept parameter either.


int received = 0;
int sent = 0;
pthread_t signaler;
pthread_t receiver;
sigset_t mask;

int main(){

    //setting up the signal mask
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL); //sets up the signal mask for this thread

    //creation of both threads
    pthread_create(&receiver, NULL, (void *)receivetest, NULL);
    pthread_create(&signaler, NULL, (void *)signaltest, NULL);


    pthread_join(signaler, NULL);
    pthread_join(receiver, NULL);

    //printing results after joining them back
    printf("I'm the main function\n");
    printf("Receieved: %d, sent: %d\n", received, sent);
    return 0;

}

void signaltest(void){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){ //sends 10 signals to receiver thread
        printf("Sending signal\n");
        pthread_kill(receiver, SIGUSR1);
        sleep(1); // Don't send signals too fast
        sent++;
    }
}

void receivetest(void){
    int c; //sigwait needs int 
    while(received < 10){ //waits for 10 signals and increments receieved
        sigwait(&mask, &c);
        printf("Signal received\n");
        received++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sending signal
Signal received
Sending signal
Signal received
Sending signal
Signal received
Sending signal
Signal received
Sending signal
Signal received
Sending signal
Signal received
Sending signal
Signal received
Sending signal
Signal received
Sending signal
Signal received
Sending signal
Signal received
I'm the main function
Receieved: 10, sent: 10
```

Comment: I see, thank you. I'm still confused about setting up the sigmask though. Why setting up the sigmask block the signals in the mask instead of opening them? Also, if I wanted to have two signals, how would I do that? Do I block both signals in the main function, and then just have receiver_a only wait for a signals and then receiver_b only wait for b signals? In that case, what should the sigwait masks be for each?

Comment: @bittersweets - `pthread_sigmask` will do what the first parameter told it to do. `SIG_BLOCK` tells it to block the signals listed in second parameter. Any thread created after `pthread_sigmask()` inherits it. It is customary to protect all threads from signals and designate a thread(s) to handle signals.

Comment: @bittersweets - for your followup question, each signal handler should have their own designated signal to wait for. It is better to define `mask` as local variable to each handler.

Answer (score 1):

Signals just don't work that way. If a thread receives a signal while that same signal is already pending, nothing happens. Please use an appropriate inter-thread communication method, not signals.

Comment: This is for a class project. We're told to use signals. (The project itself is different from the program I'm asking about, but it says to use signal generator threads and signal handler threads).

Do you think that the reason the program is freezing is because the receiver is missing signals sent to it? Have I set up the signalmask properly for it?

Comment: You might have to send the signal more than 10 times before the internal counter reaches 10. Signals were not made to be a transactional messaging mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried upping the amount sent and that indeed does make it catch. (although it still misses a lot.. when sending 100 it still freezes a good portion of the time. I guess that's why signals are no good. By using a semaphor I can sync it better, but I don't think that's what I'm supposed to do for the project...)
Anyways, thank you David Schwartz and sturcotte06